# Retrieving Event data for a fullcalendar use

Tags: fullcalendar

I haven't seen any examples where the full calendar can be populated with event data from a SQL Server query.  My events are stored in a database table.  I would like to utilize the full calendar tool to retrieve those events.

I don't know what the example's "myfeed.php" looks like but I bet I could create an equivalent "myfeed.asp" with parameters, but I don't know what it should look like.

Has anyone had success doing this?  Please share what you did.

Thanks in advance,
Paul

Comment: You will want to read up on retrieving [events as a json feed](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_data/events_json_feed/) where your calendar will access a page that will query your database for the events are return your events as json.

Answer (score 0):

I have done it exactly as Ryan says. I think you can download the php files needed and then edit them to lookup your sql server data. Our setup calls a php script when the calendar page is loaded. This php script generates a json file with all the events needed, and this is the feed that the calendar renders events from. We do the same for resources too.